# Reading a message from a named pipe using Win32

Tags: winapi, named-pipes

I have a .NET application sending data to a C++ app. They are using named pipes in message mode to send data.On the C++ side to get the data I am guessing I have to do a ReadFile to get the message into a buffer. however if the buffer is too small I will get ERROR_MORE_DATA and I should issue a ReadFile again . Its been a really long time since I've done any cpp coding, so am wondering is there is a best practices way to do this kind of reallocation and then reassembly of all they byte buffers into one buffer.
I can only think of some sort of list of pointers to buffers and you keep growing the list till youre done compute the size allocate one massive buffer and copy everything over using memcpy. Is there a nicer way anyone can think of.

Comment: How big is the message-buffer on the C# side?  If it varies, is there a realistic limit you can put on it?  What's to stop you new/mallocing, say, 1MB buffer/s on the rx side?

Comment: Yeah that  would work :-)
Thanks

Comment: You can always realloc them down afterwards, if you really want to. I don't bother with such stuff unless there's some overriding reason.  A few *BigBuffer structs/classes in your app is not going to break the memory-bank:)

Comment: not familiar with how C#'s name pipe lib sets up messages larger than 64K, but that is the system-limit last I checked (actually 65535 bytes, I believe). How large is you're buffer being sent? if the data is larger than 65535 bytes I'm amazed the C# side doesn't except.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass a packet down the pipe from the C# side first, containing the size of the data to be sent? On the C++ side read this from the pipe using ReadFile and create the buffer according to the size just received from the pipe.

Then do another ReadFile filling the correctly sized buffer with the actual data.

So, two ReadFiles on the C++ side, one to get the size of the data followed by one to get the actual data. On the C# side first send the size of the data, and then send the actual data.